# Navigating to related list tab inside napili community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, related-list, napili, lightning-community

I am now working on napili community. I have a requirement that wants me to navigate to the related list tab of a record. For that I have tried using both

> ```
>  e.force:navigateToRelatedList
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>     e.force:navigateToSObject
> ```
>
> But I am not able to achieve my result. Every time when I try with   e.force:navigateToSObject method, it keeps on navigating to the record detail page instead of navigating to the related list page. anyone knows how to do it?